# Why user is still anonymous when I try log in - Symfony 5?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, firewall

I'm a new symfony developer and I'm facing a new problem. I've created an authentication system using the guard system. However, when I try to log in entering my email and password, the user is still anonymous. Here is my code :

`User.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Exception;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UsersRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="Un compte  existe déjà avec cet email.")
 */
class User implements  UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=150, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *     pattern="/^(0|(\+)33)([1-9])([0-9]){8}$/",
     *     match=true,
     *     message="Entrez un numéro de téléphone valide, s'il vous plaît."
     * )
     * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="string", length=10, nullable=false)
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *     pattern="/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@?!$£€*]){8,}/",
     *     match=true,
     *     message="Votre mot de pass doit être une combinaison de 8 caractères contenant une majuscule, une minuscule, un chiffre et au moins un symbole spécial : @?!$£€*."
     * )
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="payment_method", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $paymentMethod;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="payment_date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $paymentDate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="creation_date", type="datetime", nullable=true, options={"default"="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"})
     */
    private $creationDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $roles;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $isVerified = false;

    /**
     * User constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->creationDate = new \DateTime();
        $this-> roles = 'ROLE_USER';
    }


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFirstname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function setFirstname(string $firstname): self
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhone(): ?string
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    public function setPhone(string $phone): self
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPaymentMethod(): ?string
    {
        return $this->paymentMethod;
    }

    public function setPaymentMethod(string $paymentMethod): self
    {
        $this->paymentMethod = $paymentMethod;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPaymentDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->paymentDate;
    }

    public function setPaymentDate(?\DateTimeInterface $paymentDate): self
    {
        $this->paymentDate = $paymentDate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreationDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->creationDate;
    }

    public function setCreationDate(\DateTimeInterface $creationDate): self
    {
        $this->creationDate = $creationDate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRoles(): string
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }

    public function setRoles(string $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
    }

    public function isVerified(): bool
    {
        return $this->isVerified;
    }

    public function setIsVerified(bool $isVerified): self
    {
        $this->isVerified = $isVerified;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

`SecurityController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
     * @param AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils
     * @return Response
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        if ($this->getUser()) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('home.html.twig');
        }

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="app_logout")
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
    }
}
```

`security.yaml`:

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\Users:
            algorithm: auto
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\UserAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

`login.html.twig`:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Log in!{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <form class="container mt-5 pb-4" style="width: 35%; method=" post">
    {% if error %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if app.user %}
        <div class="mb-3">
            You are logged in as {{ app.user.username }}, <a href="{{ path('app_logout') }}">Logout</a>
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    <h3 class="text-center pb-3">Se connecter</h3>
    <div class="row pb-4">
        <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
        <input type="email" value="{{ last_username }}" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" required
               autofocus>
    </div>
    <div class="row pb-4">
        <label for="inputPassword">Mot de passe</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" required>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token"
           value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}"
    >

    {#
    Uncomment this section and add a remember_me option below your firewall to activate remember me functionality.
    See https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/remember_me.html

    <div class="checkbox mb-3">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="_remember_me"> Remember me
        </label>
    </div>
    #}
    <div class="text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Connexion</button>
    </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

N.B : I want to check if the credentials I'm entering in the login form exist in DB, then you can log into your account otherwise you cannot go through the firewall and access your account.

Comment: Did you use the make:auth command to create the UserAuthenticator class?

Comment: Yes, I create it using the make:auth command but I create the user class using the make:entity command and not the make:user.

Comment: Hmmm.  roles is supposed to be an array of strings, not a string.  Surprised you are not getting all kinds of warnings and what not.  Since you seem to be just starting out consider create a fresh project, running make:user, make:auth and make:registration-form just to get a working example.  Once you have a simple working solution then it should be easier to troubleshoot your existing code.  Also, consider using the new authentication system instead of guard authenticators.

Comment: I found it out. The problem was in my login.html.twig file at the creation of the form tag I've forgotten to close the double quotes of the style attributes. Ty Cerdan

Comment: Glad you got it working.  First time I have seen authentication failing due to a css issue.  Still think you will have trouble when it comes time use roles.  But maybe not.

Comment: Yes, you're right but then I fixed it. Ty again